# prevent text from going into image using 'top' css attribute

Tags: html, css

I have one image below with 2 different paragraphs below it --- due to the shape of the image i am facing an issue keeping the text on the left of the image in the correct place. [See jsfiddle here to get a clearer idea](https://jsfiddle.net/pdkb1Lf5/13/) of how the image looks.

The issue I am facing with the way i have implemented the code is that the text on the left pushes up into the image when the screen becomes smaller. does anyone know how i can prevent this.

if you make the screen smaller in the jsfiddle you will see the text on the left hand side goes into the image. it is because of the following lines:

```
.left { 
   position: relative; 
   top: -100px; 
}
```

perhaps it is a case that I need to keep writing media queries for different screen sizes? Hopefully not but so far this is the only solution I can think of.

see full code below.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

[class*='col-'] {
  float: left;
}

.col-1-2 {
  width: 50%;
}

.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

[class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

[class*='col-']:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.left {
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
}

img {
  width: calc(100% - 1.2em);
  display: block;
}

.img-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrap">
  <img class="section-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcAqZ.jpg">
</div>

<div class="bottom-section">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="left col-1-2">
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p>Test test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-2">
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is expected behavior... You have explicitly told that text in `.left` to always be 100px higher than it usually is. This only looks good when the screen is a certain size. What do you want it to look like?

Comment: @Joseph i want it to remain at a constant point under the 'left-hand-side' of the image as the screen decreases in size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is doable in an acceptable way with this approach. Since the background is part of the image, it resizes with it, and that's what is causing your text to slide up into the image.

My recommendation is, to cut the image in two pieces and create the following structure:

- Put the whole thing inside a relatively positioned div
- Split your image in two and place them in your columns.
- Place the texts into a wrapper div so you have easier control over them
- Place the texts alongside the `.img-wrap` divs in your columns
- Use positioning and margins to align the elements inside the column
- Create the VS badge with CSS

Please note, that this is a very roughly done example (I have used some generated images to show how to put this together). Also, some positioning values may not be completely accurate. This is just to show you the idea.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

[class*='col-'] {
  float: left;
}

.col-1-2 {
  width: 50%;
}

.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

[class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

[class*='col-']:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.details {
  height: 50px;
}

.right .details{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
}

.right .img-wrap {
   margin-top: 50px;
}

img {
  width: calc(100% - 1.2em);
  display: block;
}

.img-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
 position: relative;
}

.vs {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  left: calc(50% - 25px - 0.3em);
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
<div class="img-wrap">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="col-1-2">
      <div class="img-wrap">
        <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" class="img-wrap" />
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <p>Test test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-2 right">
      <div class="details">
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <p>Test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="img-wrap">
        <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" class="img-wrap" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vs">VS</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used media query for your question because of your `html` code.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

[class*='col-'] {
  float: left;
}

.col-1-2 {
  width: 50%;
}

.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

[class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

[class*='col-']:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.left {
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
}

img {
  width: calc(100% - 1.2em);
  display: block;
}

.img-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .left{
    top:-85px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .left{
    top:-65px;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .left{
    top:-52px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="img-wrap">
  <img class="section-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcAqZ.jpg">
</div>

<div class="bottom-section">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="left col-1-2">
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p>Test test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-2">
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this differently, given what you want to accomplish. You could split the image into two columns, and simply offest the right column (the image and the text) to sit a bit lower. [Here](http://jsbin.com/bonuqowale/edit?html,css,output) is an example.

Another alternative would be to put:

```
.left{
    top: 10vw;
}
```

or a similar value which is responsive. 10vw will always equal 10% of the viewport width, so when the screen gets smaller, the offset gets smaller as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you scale the image in proportion to the screen size, but the 100px offset is not scaled proportionally.  So as your image shrinks, the white space at the bottom also changes size.

Scaling items in relation to the height of the container is usually a mild pain, and would require major restructuring of your html.

Here is an alternate version: https://jsfiddle.net/pdkb1Lf5/14/

```
.versus {
  display: block;
  position: absolute; bottom:50%; left:50%; margin-left:-45px; 
  width: 90px; height:90px; line-height:90px;
  background:#fff; border-radius: 50%; 
  text-align:center; 
  font-family:sans-serif; font-size:40px; text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

It requires that you split up your two images.  This method will be bulletproof, but notice that it passes off the failure-to-scale onto the "versus" graphic, which is much safer.

Alternatively, you could experiment with VH units, if you are permitted to ignore ie8.